# What happened to original series of Javascript lecture on Yahoo!?

Tags: javascript, video

Referring to the link

http://www.catonmat.net/blog/learning-javascript-programming-language-through-video-lectures/

Is there anyone who keeps a copy of the video from last time, or know any mirror that have the video?

Its a shame that Yahoo! doesn't seem to host the video anymore, considering the good content as was mentioned in the link I gave.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxAXlJEmNMg&feature=related

Should be able to find EVERYTHING on youtube.

Answer (score 0):

Walkerneo is right. Everything is on Youtube now.

Actually most of the things could be found in [yuilibrary's Channel - YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/user/yuilibrary/videos)